# Multiple post requests in restful web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, rest

I am trying to get a restful web service working using code from http://blog.dlwelch.com/?p=390

There is an Operation Contract for Post like this:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json")]
    bool JSONDataPost(Person PersonObject);
```

This is working correctly. I can post data like ...

```
string data = @"{""PersonObject"":{""FirstName"":""Fred"",""Surname"":""Smith""}}";
```

and I can, in my web service, extract the data passed and do what I want with it.

I have two questions. The method JSONDataPost(Person PersonObject) returns a bool. What I receive in the calling application is:

```
"{\"JSONDataPostResult\":true}"
```

If this is called using JQuery and Ajax - the return is not valid JSON. How can I get the web service to return valid JSON?

The second question is: How can I create another method that is called using POST?

I need another one like:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json")]
    bool JSONDataPost_Interests(Interests InterestsObject);
```

If I add another OperationContract like that the web service falls over. How do you have multiple methods that are called using Post?

Comment: `the return is not valid JSON` Why not?

Comment: Ahh, okay, it is valid JSON, just worked out how to read what is coming back. So, my only question now is how to create multiple requests that can be called using POST that will do different things.

Comment: What does `the web service falls over.` mean? What error do you get?

Comment: It reports Server Error 500. When you call a web service like this using GET you can append to the querystring to call the right method. How do you get POST requests to call the right method? I got the impression that as soon as I had two OperationContracts whose Method = "POST", it went wrong. I removed the second method, published the web service again and it worked okay again.

Comment: Martin, i don't think there is anything wrong with your server code. It seems you have problem with your *requests*

Comment: But, when I call the web service, how does the web service know which method I am calling. There is nothing in the POST that says 'I am calling JSONDataPost' - it just seems to know and does it. But, as soon as I create another OperationContract that accepts POSTS - it stops working. How does the web service know which method is to be called?